# How international are the SO careers CV entries?

Tags: support, jobs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Careers internationally](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29665/careers-internationally)

I'm considering paying and posting my CV via careers SO. I'm just wondering how much international audience the site has or will get? The success of the careers database wins or falls depending on a certain **critical mass**. This is also depends on the country itself.

I'm pretty sure we get to this mass in a country as the U.S.A., but how is it with the different European countries?

Would it, for instance, be possible to see *how many CV's there are in Careers SO per country*?

I think that in a country where I live (The Netherlands), general recruiters will not look for stack overflow careers, because there are a lot of generic job websites where people leave their CV. But for those 5-10% real software development companies that really search for the quality it may be a "**honey pot**".

Comment: +1. More than seeing CV per country, what I really would like to see is a measure - even if indirect - about recruiters per country/state. Is Stack Overflow going to help me land that job in Fiji?

Comment: answered http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/29665/careers-internationally