# Careers internationally

Tags: discussion, jobs, recruitment

Looking at the new careers site I wonder what will be its international appeal. Is it likely to be very US focused or what would be it's geographic distribution.

Do you think it will be worth filing a CV from an European location?

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28901/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a breakdown of the top 15 locations who have filed after removing USA:

```
London, England United Kingdom      221
Toronto, Ontario Canada              79
Sydney, New South Wales Australia    73
Bangalore, Karnataka India           57
Moscow, Moskva Russia                52
Melbourne, Victoria Australia        49
Paris, Ile-de-France France          42
Israel                               40
Vancouver, British Columbia Canada   38
Montreal, Quebec Canada              34
Cambridge, England United Kingdom    32
Stockholm, Stockholm Sweden          31
Ottawa, Ontario Canada               30
Singapore                            28
England United Kingdom               28
```

The audience is widely distributed, so your answer is YES - it's well worth it!

Comment: what about *with* the USA? it might help to know what sort of competition we face

Comment: Doe this make careers the best candidate for l10n then?

Comment: Are these stats generated somewhere? The data above can change significantly during the time.